# Is this an existing theorem in Complex Numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

$\boxed{\text{Conjecture}:}$
Let the sum of primitive roots of the equation $z^n-1=0$ be $C$. Let $P$ and $L$ be such that $n= P \times L $ and $\gcd (P,L)=1$ . Let the sum of primitive roots of $z^P-1=0$ be $k$ and sum of primitive roots of $z^L-1=0$ be $m.$ Now $k , m \in [0,1,-1]$. Then ,  $$C= k \times m.$$

Note : I found this pattern in complex numbers today. I am not aware if this an existing theorem or not. I dont seem to find this anywhere.

Comment: This is [multiplicativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function) of the Möbius function. Here ( https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1892410/the-m%C3%B6bius-function-is-the-sum-of-the-primitive-nth-roots-of-unity ) is a proof that $\mu(n)=\begin{cases}  0&\text{if }n\text{ is not squarefree}\\ (-1)^{\text{# prime divisors}}&\text{if }n\text{ squarefree}\end{cases}$ is actually that sum. It's then clear that this $\mu$ is multiplicative.

Comment: Also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2228443/305862)